# Map JSON CDC data in cache value to Ignite sqlline thin client tables

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ignite, thin-client, sqlline

Basically, I am trying to send CDC JSON data via connectors from Kafka topics to Ignite Cache. And for transformation purpose I want to look up this JSON data in table view in Ignite. How can I map these JSON fields to ignite SQLline table's columns?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly it should be pretty straightforward.
It's possible to leverage Java classes for that. You can [specify](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/SQL/sql-api#querysqlfield-annotation) a structure that would correspond to your JSON structure. Along with the additional cache configuration (`CacheConfiguration.setIndexedTypes(…​)`) property it will make it SQL-enabled.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. I did the same and in visorcmd I can see that data is retrieved. But I am unable to fetch the data for my table. it is showing "Failed to set schema for DB connection for thread"

Comment: Does it mean that my data is not getting serialized properly? Or any other configuration like query entity I am missing.